# input texts dependant with each other with autocomplete feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, autocomplete

I have created 2 input texts, one is ID and the other is Name. If I type an ID in the 1st input text then press tab or click the 2nd input text (using onfocusout in HTML), the 2nd input text will automatically filled with name assigned to that ID. Example, typing ID '001' will display 'Elnora'. Likewise, typing 'Soo' in the 2nd input text (and press tab) will display '010' in the 1st input text. Basically it is a one-to-one mapping based on index number. This works flawlessly as you can see in my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azzaeff/xmgrj08x/).

```
    var scholaridlists = ["001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010"];
    var scholarlists = ["Elnora","Henry","Scotty","Bruna","Shirley","Modesto","Lissa","Davida","Margherita","Soo"];

 function idtoname() {
    var ids=document.getElementById("currentscholaridlist").value;
    var a = scholaridlists.indexOf(ids);
    document.getElementById("currentscholarlist").value =scholarlists[a];
}

 function nametoid() {
    var names=document.getElementById('currentscholarlist').value;
    var b = scholarlists.indexOf(names);
    document.getElementById('currentscholaridlist').value = scholaridlists[b];
}
```

However, as not everyone remembers anyone's IDs and/or Names, I would like to implement an Autocomplete feature as well, so that whenever someone type an ID/Name, a suggested list of ID/Name will appear. I am attempting to use JQueryUI Autocomplete as in my other [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azzaeff/xmgrj08x/). The Autocomplete works, but pressing tab/click the other input text does not show the other assigned pairing.

```
 $( function() {
     "use strict";

var scholaridlists = ["001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010"];
$( "#currentscholaridlist" ).autocomplete({      source: scholaridlists, minLength:3, maxShowItems:5    });


   var scholarlists = ["Elnora","Henry","Scotty","Bruna","Shirley","Modesto","Lissa","Davida","Margherita","Soo"];
  $( "#currentscholarlist" ).autocomplete({      source: scholarlists, minLength:3, maxShowItems:5    });

} ); 

 function idtoname() {
    var ids1=document.getElementById("currentscholaridlist").value;
    var a = scholaridlists.indexOf(ids1);
    var ids2= a;
    document.getElementById("currentscholarlist").value =scholarlists[ids2];
}

 function nametoid() {
    var names1=document.getElementById('currentscholarlist').value;
    var b = scholarlists.indexOf(names1);
    var names2 = b;
    document.getElementById('currentscholaridlist').value = scholaridlists[names2];
}
```

Should anyone have a solution for this problem, I would prefer that the Ids/names array lists remained in JS and not in HTML using select/option. Also, the Ids are not necessarily in numbers and in alphabetical/numbering order as shown in the Jsfiddle (I could use Ids like A123, SC001A etc).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few changes need to be done.

Use [**onblur**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="currentscholaridlist" onblur="idtoname()">
<br/>
<input type="text" id="currentscholarlist" onblur="nametoid(this)">
<br/>
```

The source array need to be outside the function.This is because `idtoname` & `nametoid` are not in scope of `$(function(){..})`. So they will not have access to the array

**JS**

```
   var scholaridlists = ["001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010"];
   var scholarlists = ["Elnora", "Henry", "Scotty", "Bruna", "Shirley", "Modesto", "Lissa", "Davida", "Margherita", "Soo"];
   $(function() {
      // Rest of the code
   });

   function idtoname() {
     // rest of the code
   }

   function nametoid() {
     // rest of the code
   }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xmgrj08x/8/)

Comment: Wow, never thought that the solution are so simple. Thank you so much @brk ! Anyway, previously I did try moving the arrays outside but it didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with onblur vs onfocusout? Also, out of curiosity if you happen to know, why idtoname() does not have 'this' inside the bracket as opposed to nametoid(this)? Sorry as I'm fairly new with this JS/HTML thing. Thanks again!